# Google Charts axis title

Tags: google-visualization

is it possible to add axis title, on Google Charts (Line Chart), and not to change Tick marks?

Tnx in adv!

Answer (score 4):

Yes you can. Here's a slightly modified example from:
http://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/?type=visualization#line_chart

The trick is to gets axis labels for two vertical axis (haven't figured out how to do that).

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  google.load('visualization', '1', {packages: ['corechart']});
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function drawVisualization() {
    // Create and populate the data table.
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('string', 'x');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Cats');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Blanket 1');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Blanket 2');
    data.addRow(["A", 1, 1, 0.5]);
    data.addRow(["B", 2, 0.5, 1]);
    data.addRow(["C", 4, 1, 0.5]);
    data.addRow(["D", 8, 0.5, 1]);
    data.addRow(["E", 7, 1, 0.5]);
    data.addRow(["F", 7, 0.5, 1]);
    data.addRow(["G", 8, 1, 0.5]);
    data.addRow(["H", 4, 0.5, 1]);
    data.addRow(["I", 2, 1, 0.5]);
    data.addRow(["J", 3.5, 0.5, 1]);
    data.addRow(["K", 3, 1, 0.5]);
    data.addRow(["L", 3.5, 0.5, 1]);
    data.addRow(["M", 1, 1, 0.5]);
    data.addRow(["N", 1, 0.5, 1]);

    // Create and draw the visualization.
    new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('visualization')).
        draw(data, {curveType: "function",
                    width: 500, height: 400,
                    vAxis: {maxValue: 10, title: "my Axis"}}
            );
  }


  google.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization);
</script>
```